# Node CLI App - copy a set of files

Tags: node.js, command-line-interface

I am creating a  NODE JS CLI app that will generate a scaffolding for the user based on the options the user provides.

I am stuck at the part where the cli app needs to copy a set of files from its repository and place in the users working directory. The code i am using is:

```
    fs.copy('./template/core', '/', function (err) 
    {
      if (err) return console.error(err)
      console.log("success!")
    });
```

The template/core folder is present in the cli app project hierarchy

when i run the command ,  it gives me:

{ Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat './template/core'
  errno: -2,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'lstat',
  path: './template/core' }

I have done an npm install -g and could see the template/core file in the /usr/lib/node_modules//

Any help in resolving this issue would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to copy a file with a source relative to the current working directory (`./`), which should be relative to the CLI script file (if I understand you correctly). For that, you need to copy relative to `__dirname`.

Also, your destination (`/`) reflects the root of the file system, but your text says that you want to copy files to the current working directory, so you should use `.`

Those two things combined would result in this:

```
const path = require('path');
fs.copy(path.resolve(__dirname, 'template/core'), '.', function(err) { ... });
```